# multidimensional numpy array __eq__

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a bi-dimensional `np.array` like

```
x = np.array([[1,2], [4,5], [4,6], [5,4], [4,5]])
```

now I want the indices where x is equal to `[4,5]` (`-> [1, 4]`). The operator `==` works in a different way:

```
x == [4,5]
array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

but I want something like `[False, True, False, False, True]`. Is it ok to do an `and`?

Usually the array is very big and I have to do it a lot of times, so I need a very fast way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should be the numpy-way:

```
x = np.array([[1,2], [4,5], [4,6], [5,4], [4,5]])
(x == [4,5]).all(1)

#out: array([False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

No prior experience with numpy, but this works for a standard array:

```
x = [[1, 2], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 4], [4, 5]]

indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(x) if v == [4, 5]]
# gives [1, 4]

matches = [v == [4, 5] for v in x]
# gives [False, True, False, False, True]
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention I want a numpy solution